# Style as resources for custom user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am trying to modify Extended WPF toolkit wizard control which is a Custom control it has a default style in generic.xaml file but now I want to modify it so based on Wizard type it changes its style completely

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Wizard}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="WizardType" Value="Normal">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource StandartWizardTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

this is how I have its generic.xaml modified but StandardWizardTemplate is not resolved during insistence

```
<Style x:Key="StandartWizardTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:Wizard}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0F0F0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
    //Content of default template before modification
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Same file contains another style definition which changes Page ControlTemplate Based on trigger so I though I will be able to do the same thing for Wizard

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WizardPage}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="PageType" Value="Blank">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF0F0F0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BlankWizardPageTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="PageType" Value="Exterior">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="ExteriorPanelBackground" Value="#E3EFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ExteriorWizardPageTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="PageType" Value="Interior">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF0F0F0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderBackground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource InteriorWizardPageTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Can anyone provide me with the right Styling implementation so that my Wizard Custom Control can be styled in the same way as Page does?

Comment: setting a style is a style trigger seems pretty unusual for me

Comment: what do u mean? this is a them from extended WPF toolkit Wizard control and setting WizardPage Template based on trigger is really interesting so can u post answer on how to switch wizard control style itself based on trigger of WizardType dependency property?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found solution for this problem, All i had to do was to create new ResourceDictionary and declare Wizard ControlTemplate with key set. After that inside Generic.xaml I created Marge Resource Dictionary and included all separate Control template dictionaries inside

After All my generic.xaml looks in this way now.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:CuratioCMS.Client.UI.Core.Converters"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CuratioCMS.Client.UI.Controls">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./NormalWizardStyle.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./StepBased.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./MixedModeWizard.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Converters:WizardPageButtonVisibilityConverter x:Key="WizardPageButtonVisibilityConverter" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Wizard}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="WizardType" Value="Normal">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NormalModeWizardTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="WizardType" Value="StepWisivle">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource StepModeWizardTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="WizardType" Value="MixedMode">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MixedModeWizardTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0F0F0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```